# How to refer to a specific line or range of lines in github?

Tags: github

If you want to add a reference to a specific line or a range of lines, it would be nice to get  an URL that does that.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Note that the problem with the `#Lxx-Lyy` is that (from [this post](http://dropshado.ws/post/8347781227/github-link-to-source-code-with-commit-tree)):

> **source files are subject to change**, or even be removed, so there’s **no guarantee that your link will always point to the correct place**.
>   By default, GitHub project pages link to the most current version of the source. A better practice is to link to a specific commit, where the content of source files are not subject to versioning.
>
> To view a GitHub project at a certain commit, click on the tree link in the commit header, or just press <kbd>t</kbd> on your keyboard. You can then browse the project files, and link to sources of this commit, i.e.

http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/27291ff06ddb655f90a8d1eada71f7ac61499b12/src/css.js#L171-L185.

> Note that the only difference in the URL is changing the branch name master with the commit SHA.

+1 tip from Paul Irish:

> **plus you only need 4 characters of the SHA in the URL**... it figures it out.
>   I usually truncate to 7ish characters.
>
> Nice: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/27291ff/src/css.js#L171-185

---

If you have a GitHub page which does not reference a sha1, **type <kbd>y</kbd>**:
that will **reload that same page with the current SHA1**.

Comment: I said '(or version of the file you want to refer to)' but your description is more precise :-)

Comment: Is there a way to do same thing with pull requests?

Comment: @llamerr not sure: what did you try? (you can describe that in a separate question, actually)

Comment: good idea, thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48911087/how-to-select-comment-on-a-range-of-lines-in-github-pull-request

Comment: FYI: the `#Lxx-xx` syntax and the SHA truncation features are both available on GitLab as well.

Comment: @drmercer True. Although I don't remember if those features were there (on gitlab.com) 5+ years ago, when I originally wrote that answer.

Comment: How can I comment to the selected range of code ? (not in pull request but any ordinary repo)

Comment: @RaihanurRahman As far as I know, commenting on multi-line reference/range is only supported for PR (Pull Request)

Comment: Referencing the code of a certain commit seems to be the default behavior for referencing in GitHub right now.

Answer (score 14):

If you go the the file (or version of the file you want to refer to), click the line number (or hold shift down to select a range).

=> you will see that the URL changes (it adds something like `#L21-L23` to the URL).

Just copy the URL.