# How can I suggest multiple lines be changed in markdown

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I first encountered on GitHub the "suggestion" code block, identified by

````
```suggestion
change
```
````

This offers to replace the line immediately before with what is inside the fence. But what about if I want to replace multiple lines?

I'd like to think this is possible, but I cannot find documentation of this feature anywhere. I have at least learned that the key terms to use are [fenced code block](https://github.github.com/gfm/#fenced-code-block) and [info string](https://github.github.com/gfm/#info-string) but the best I can come up with is that the info string (other than the first token) is unspecified.

Is this capability documented anywhere? It is emminently useful in code reviews.

**Edit: This is a markdown question not a GitHub question**

So far, it appears to be a GitHub-unique feature. That may be the answer, but telling me how to use the GitHub GUI is **not** addressing the question.

Comment: I'm having the same problem on Azure Devops, so it's not Github Exclusive.

Comment: It was never GitHub exclusive; my question arose from using Bitbucket (Atlassian). What I've learned is that, while fenced code blocks are a feature, the use of them as a multi-line suggestion does appear to be a GitHub-unique feature.

Answer (score 106):

To add a comment on multiple lines, click and drag to select the range of lines, then click the blue comment icon.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the video. I was selecting the multiple lines but clicking the + on the first line which doesn't work, you need to select the + on the last line.

Comment: Give this man a medal! ️

Comment: OMG I clicked the first line instead of last line and wondered "How bad it doesn't support this!".

Answer (score 3):

Multi-line Github change request can be achieved by combining multi-line commenting and change request feature.

> Step 1. Select multi-line commenting feature for lines that needs to be changed-
> [How to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48911087/how-to-select-comment-on-a-range-of-lines-in-github-pull-request)
>
> Step 2. then press <cmd+g>

Tada!!!
Add your change request.

Comment: I’m sorry if it wasn’t clear, but this is a Markdown question more than a GitHub question. At work we use Bitbucket, which also has limited support for the `suggestion` fenced code block. I have come to accept that Markdown varies widely, so the GitHub implementation may well be a unique feature.

Answer (score 1):

Github released multi-line code suggestions on February 26, 2020:

https://github.blog/changelog/2020-02-26-multi-line-code-suggestions-beta/

> To select a multi-line code block, you can either:
>
> - click and hold to the right of a line number, drag and then release the mouse when you’ve reached the last line of the desired selection; or
> - click on a line number, hold Shift, click on a second line number and click the "+" button to the right of the second line number.
>
> Once you've selected the code block, click the diff icon and edit the text within the suggestion block.