# comment multiple lines in gitlab without blue icon?

Tags: github

I want to comment multiple lines in a commit. I googled for that and found multiple instructions that all mention that one have to click the blue plus icon like [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/commenting-on-a-pull-request) or at [How to select/comment on a range of lines in github pull request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48911087/how-to-select-comment-on-a-range-of-lines-in-github-pull-request):

[image]

However, when I hove over this section with my mouse, no blue icon appears. I tried it in Chrome and Firefox (using Ubuntu 20.20).

Any chance that I can select multiple lines without the icon? Or what can I do to enable the icon?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That actually seems supported on GitLab [only now (Jan. 2021)](https://twitter.com/gitlab/status/1362747528219918338):

Users can now click at the beginning of a line and drag the comment marker across multiple lines to highlight and reference multiple lines when leaving feedback in an MR.

See [GitLab 13.8](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/01/22/gitlab-13-8-released/#click-and-drag-multiline-merge-request-comments) (January 2021)

> ### Click and drag multiline merge request comments
>
> Commenting on a single line is great for simple kinds of code review feedback, but often a comment addresses multiple lines in the diff.
> For instance, a portion of a logic block, a paragraph of prose, or an entire function. This forces users to choose a single line to provide feedback, but the feedback refers to other portions of the file.
>
> [image: mr multiline comment]
>
> Previously, users could select multiple lines after posting a comment by adjusting line numbers up and down from the original comment point. Now, users can click at the beginning of a line and drag the comment marker across multiple lines to highlight and reference multiple lines when leaving feedback in a merge request.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/reviewing_and_managing_merge_requests.html#commenting-on-multiple-lines) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/280608).

Comment: :/ that needs some re-thinking.

Comment: @dtc Do you mean the feature, as currently implemented, is not practical?

Comment: ya mainly cause I had to diagonally drag from the left to the right so it's a bit non-intuitive. also, I'm lagging at the moment on a page where im trying it out and it's not a particularly large merge request.