# How to comment on the range of code lines in GitHub using touch screen devices?

Tags: github, pull-request

My question is similar to [How to select/comment on a range of lines in github pull request?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48911087/3240681) but I would like to do this on touch screen device like iPad, where there's no hardware mouse and keyboard.

How to comment (and suggest a code change) on the range of code lines using touch screen devices?

Answer (score 1):

I [mentioned that feature before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58190804/6309), and it is discussed in [this discussion](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/49954)

But a touch screen does not seem to be supported at this time (Q3 2023)

The [documentation itself](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/reviewing-changes-in-pull-requests/commenting-on-a-pull-request#adding-comments-to-a-pull-request) mentions:

> "Hover over the line of code where you'd like to add a comment, and click the blue comment icon. To add a comment on multiple lines, click and drag to select the range of lines, then click the blue comment icon."

That looks like mouse-only for now.